# Applications of polar decomposition in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, graphs, text-classification, semantics, singular-value-decomposition

Assume there exists a new and very efficient algorithm for calculating the polar decomposition of a matrix $A=UP$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $P$ is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix. Would there be any interesting applications in Machine Learning? Maybe topic modeling? Or page ranking? I am interested in references to articles and books.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Maybe have a look at geometric deep learning. There are some models there that make use of adjacency matrices and other matrices.

Comment: Thank you @nbro. Do you have any references I could check out?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't have a specific reference on GDL that talks about adjacency matrices (because it's been a while since I had to deal with GDL), but I guess that many papers on graph neural networks will talk about it. Maybe ask another question on the site about it. And I (or someone else) will try to provide a more formal answer.